# Why does the compiler init this variable to the wrong value? Is this an alignment issue?

Tags: c, memory, compiler-construction, memory-alignment

I'm working with an embedded C compiler (ARM cortex-m3 chip) and it seems to initialize the wrong value to a struct.  Why does this happen? If it's an alignment issue, shouldn't the compiler know to align an int32u to a 4-byte boundary?

Note: the printf merely throws bytes out of the serial port. There is no stdio.h implementation on this chip.

```
typedef struct
{
    int32u startTime; 
    int16u length;
    int32u offTime;
} Cycle;

Cycle cycle = 
{
    315618000, 
    1200,
    0
};


void init()
{
   printf("\r\nInitialized! Cycle Start: %d", cycle.startTime);

   cycle.startTime = 315618000;
   cycle.length = 1200;

   printf(" Cycle Start: %d", cycle.startTime);

}
```

> Output: 
>   Initialized! Cycle Start: 631237200 Cycle Start: 315618000

**Note:**: This NOT a printf issue.  The debugger verifies the value in memory as 631237200 as well.

Comment: `"%d"` requires an `int` argument. It's likely to work if `int` is 32 bits, but just to be sure try changing the format from `"%d"` to `"%lu"` and explicitly casting the argument to `unsigned long`.

Comment: Does your compiler document `void main()` as a correct definition for `main`? Do you have `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Although I totally agree that `%d` is wrong, I doubt this is about conversion specifiers (or even integer sizes), as it seems work for the second `printf()`.

Comment: No, this is tiny chip, the first time cycle is referred to is here. (no corruption elsewhere).  Also, no libraries to include, see updated note on printf.

Comment: Have you tried initializing all the member of struct, currently you are just initializing two members.

Comment: @praks411 yes, they're all initialized.

Comment: Why not initialize cycle using the field names i.e. `startTine = 315618000`?

Comment: What would be `printf()`ed for `length` before being assigned a value in `main()`?

Comment: @EdHeal also done .startTime = 315618000, same result.

Comment: Append a `U` or a `UL` like `.startTime = 315618000U`. Try both.

Comment: @alk, length gets initialized properly.

Comment: Please see the updated Note: This **NOT a printf issue** debugger shows the same values.

Comment: Not sure if this can help, but 631237200 = 315618000*2 + 1200. I didn't have an idea of why it's initialized this way yet

Comment: @MandoMando Out of curiosity, what is `sizeof(cycle.startTime)` ? And is there any chance your compiler is optimizing out the get-val from the structure and just throwing the immediate value assigned in the prior stmts into the printf arg list (which would be dreadful) ?

Comment: I agree that the `printf` format *probably* isn't the issue, but when you're tracking down a problem (and by definition you don't yet know the cause) it's worth eliminating all possible sources of error.

Comment: @Doraj: +1 for this nice catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some embedded systems, static initialization is not set up to happen automatically. This goes against C specifications, but sometimes that's the way it is. Note that this may be true for both data and bss segments i.e. you may find that uninitialized statics may NOT be initialized to zero either.

The solution to this is, unfortunately, system specific. You may find something in your complier system documentation that lets you invoke the initialization of the static elements.

Comment: Normally this means that the C compiler expects some runtime component to zero out the .bss, and load the correct (const) data segments at the proper place in memory. Lacking such a runtime, you'll have to write it yourself. (Or you've simply messed up when creating the linker map, or discarded the sections when transforming the binary to be booted, e.g.during objcopy from elf to a .bin file)

Comment: For the data segment, the compiler generates initializer functions for initialized statics. These need to be called in the CRT (before main). This may be useful. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]  My suggested below that sizeof(int) == 2 is likely *not* the issue as `" Cycle Start: %d", cycle.startTime` readily prints out values > 64k.  I suspect a padding issue.  But the lower recommendation about printf() apply, even though they do not explain this issue.

---

The initialization of `cycle` in effect does a `cycle.startTime = 315618000`.  Your int/unsigned size is likely 2, therefore the initialization overflows.  Instead:

```
Cycle cycle = {
  315618000LU, 
  1200,
  0
  };
```

Your `printf()` should also use the matching format specifier for uint32_t

```
#include <inttypes.h>
printf("Cycle Start: %" PRIu32 "\n", cycle.startTime);
printf("Length     : %" PRIu16 "\n", cycle.length);
```

Comment: Could the OP be so kind and comment on this answer, as I'm really curious whether the `LU` appendix did the job.

Comment: @alk  I _think_ that since the accepted answer implies static initialization did _not_ happen, what was printed was whatever happened to be in uninitialized `cycle.startTime`, maybe from previous runs.  Ah, the foibles of the embedded world.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably find out what is happening by viewing the assembly code. I don't know if your compiler is GCC. If it is the -S flag should produce an assembly file named as the input file but with a .s extension.

With that you should be able to view what values are being assigned to the global structure variable.

Another thing that could be wrong is the printf function. If you did not use a function prototype that declares it as a varargs function like `int printf(const char *fmt, ...)` then the call will be done wrong.

On at least one architecture I know of, all vararg entries have maximum alignment because the function does not know what it is getting. Normal functions pass values on the stack with the declared type alignment. If printf does not have a prototype the C language will assume all arguments are int and try to pass them that way. Meanwhile the printf function itself will be trying to pull arguments as varargs and it could easily slip by a few bytes here and there.