# In Eclipse-based IDE global variable initialized to a wrong value - troubleshooting

Tags: c

**The Problem**

---

I am using Eclipse-based compiler to program a microcontroller. One of the global variables that I initialize to `0` outside of my `main()` function gets initialized to some arbitrary value. In debugger view, whenever I re-initialize the variable manually and restart the code by pressing the 'start from the beginning' button without re-building the code, the said variable retains that value - it's hard to explain but perhaps that may be a clue. Also, other global variables around it get initialized fine, but they are set to values other than `0` - perhaps a second clue.

---

**What has been done so far to find the cause**

---

In short - not a lot :) With limited experience all I could do is look up some answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406751/why-does-the-compiler-init-this-variable-to-the-wrong-value-is-this-an-alignmen) - which actually has an answer but I cannot make much sense of it unfortunately. Where would I look to troubleshoot such an issue and how do I find the .bss information among all the files created by the compiler? Below are some things that I have found trying to figure out what the problem is.

---

**Some clues**

---

There are some peculiar things about this issue that I have observed. Firstly, the global variable declaration looks something like this:

```
uint16_t compareValue1 = (0U);
uint16_t compareValue2 = (600U);
uint16_t pwm_compareValue = (0U);
```

`compareValue1` is the variable that gets initialized to an arbitrary value (albeit it seems to more often than not to get initialized to 232 whenever I build and debug code). `pwm_compareValue` is a variable that I am not using at the moment and hence cannot view in debug view unless I use it somewhere in the code. Here is the interesting part - whenever I **do use** `hrpwm_compareValue` in my code, **both** `hrpwm_compareValue` and `compareValue1` get initialized to their respective values of `0`. As mentioned above, `compareValue2` gets initialized to `600` consistently and without error.

Here's one more - the following snippet comes from `main.o.lst` file:

```
 446 0000 5802       .short 600
 447                 .global compareValue1
 448                 .section .bss.compareValue1,"aw",%nobits
 449                 .align 1
 452                compareValue1:
 453 0000 0000       .space 2
 454                 .global compareValue2
 455                 .section .data.compareValue2,"aw",%progbits
 456                 .align 1
 459                compareValue2:
 460 0000 5802       .short 600
 461                 .global pwm_compareValue
 462                 .section .bss.pwm_compareValue,"aw",%nobits
 463                 .align 1
 466                pwm_compareValue:
```

If the variable is initialized from inside `main()` function, then it assumes the value of `0` as one would expect.

Now, I will be looking more into this issue to understand it further, however what I am hoping to get out of asking this question is how do I approach these sorts of issues? Can I extract any useful information from the code snippet above? Are the preprocessing flags of any use in this case and if so, how can I make use of them? And has anyone encountered the same issue before - what may cause such program behaviour in general?

Comment: These are definitions, not just declarations. And that has nothing to do with eclipse. It seems not even related to C as asked. See [ask].

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact it is Eclipse-based or IDE or whatever, really..

Comment: Disable optimization. Make sure a full reset is done.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you both for clarifying - I am asking because at this point I have no clue as to where to look for a solution and whether it's IDE-related or else.

Comment: Use your hardware debugger to put a write watch on the global?

Comment: @leppie Optimization seems to be off by default

Comment: @MartinJames What exactly do you mean? As in add a watch expression on the globals?

Comment: @agrus yes, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @MartinJames Well that's what shows me the value `232` instead of the expected `0` - it just jumps over the preprocessing sequence and halts at some default breakpoint inside main when I press "Debug" - hence I cannot trace anything that happens before (I think)

Comment: You should be able to trace through the crt initialization.

Comment: If your watch has trapped a write of 232, then you should be able to examine what code executed that write.

Comment: @MartinJames I spent the last few hours reading about all this stuff but I can't figure it out yet - the watch expression in my debugger just gives the value and the type of variable, no other information is provided unfortunately,

Answer (score 1):

Microcontrollers has to do initialization before calling `main()` after each reset. Initialization function is called by your **startup** code. This is the place where you should be looking.

For example, keil compiler, crates a `__main` function that is called by the startup, this function initializes global variables, clear global zero-initialized variables and then call user's `main`.

The question is, which microcontroller are you using and with which startup code?

This link has to clarify: http://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/04/14/text-data-and-bss-code-and-data-size-explained/

Comment: Good response and terrific link - although I am yet to figure out the issue the articles on the website are very informative. I am working with an ARM Cortex M4-based micro with the start-up code provided by the manufacturer. In short, it seems to do go through the sequence like the one you suggested - it first initializes and loads initialized data into RAM and then moves onto `.bss` section to load zero-initialized data. Is there any way to check the values each variable gets initialized with, perhaps from the `.elf` file?

Comment: As other have commented, some code is writing to your variable and a write watch point should reveal the writer. Are you having trouble to set a write watch on the variable?

Comment: I am yet to try the watch points - I will let you know how that goes. So far I have tried deassembling object files to see which values the given variable initializes to - aside from some interesting information, no luck otherwise. Is it of any use or is a watch point a preferred method of debugging in this case?